# How do you map an object from a transposed/inverted range that is able to perform key-value lookups in GAS?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, key-value, associative

I'm scripting a custom `function()` that needs to display a specific key-value from a range named `ioRange` that consists of cells "A1:B3" shown below.

```
// google sheets ui

/*
            [A]            [B]       
 [1]   ||    ID       ||    1      ||
 [2]   ||    NAME     ||    Elon   ||
 [3]   ||    EMOJI    ||         ||
*/
```

From what I’ve gathered so far, this kind of key-value table structure is no good for google sheets to process cleanly. For instance, with the cells above, google scripts kind of creates a pseudo [associative array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) as a range, but formatted with google scripts row brackets and other nuances like quotes:

```js
var ioRange = ss.getRange("A1:B3").getValues()

console.log(ioRange)
// => "[[ID, 1], [NAME, Elon], [EMOJI, ]]"
```

I’m currently stuck on converting `ioRange` into a key-value mapped object named `ioObject`, having issues with `push()` -ing new values to `ioObject` in the correct format.  Below is my bad code, but hopefully it gives an idea of what I’m trying to accomplish.

```js
//  bad code

var ioObject = {}
for (row = 0; row < ioRange.length; ++row) {
    ioObject.push(`${ioRange[row][0]}: "${ioRange[row][1]} as"`)
}
```

I want the `ioObject` to result in this output:

```js
//  desired output

console.log(JSON.stringify(ioObject))
/* => '{
            "ID": "1", 
            "NAME": "Elon",   
            "EMOJI": ""
        }'
*/
```

So that I can do key-value lookups like this:

```js
//  success!

console.log(ioObject["NAME"])
// => "Elon"
```

I checked out [javascript - Creating hash array in Google Apps Script - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650771/creating-hash-array-in-google-apps-script) and [Hash Tables in Javascript](http://www.mojavelinux.com/articles/javascript_hashes.html) but no luck.

---

**SOLUTION:**

```js
// ✅ solved w/ escaping double quotes
var ioObject = {}
for (row = 0; row < ioRange.length; ++row) {
    ioObject[ioRange[io][0]]=ioRange[io][1]
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(ioObject))
// => '{"ID"="1", "NAME"="Elon", "EMOJI"=""}'

//  success!
console.log(ioObject["NAME"])
// => "Elon"
```

Comment: `[[ID, 1], [NAME, Elon], [EMOJI, ]]` is a google script two dimensional array of a range with two columns and 3 rows.

Comment: Try this: `for(var row=0; row<ioRange.length;++row) {
    ioObject[ioRange[row][0]]=ioRange[row][1]);
}`

Comment: @Cooper When I read this question again, because I noticed that my answer was not suitable for this, I would like to delete my answer. And I think that your comment is suitable for this question. So can you post it as an answer? It will be useful for resolving OP's issue.

Comment: @Cooper I tried  `ioObject[ioRange[row][0]]=ioRange[row][1])`  which got me 90% there, thanks for that. The only issue remaining is quoting…can you help me get the key and values in double quotes? Currently the result of `ioObject` is: `// => "{ID=1, NAME=Elon, Emoji=}"` .

Comment: For clarity, the quoting output of `ioObject` needs to result in: `// => “{‘ID’=1, ‘NAME’=‘Elon’, ‘Emoji’=‘’}"`. ...or something comparable to this. I tried adding them in as a strings with “+” `concat()` methods, but was it keeps breaking it.  Really appreciate the help @Tanaike and @Cooper :)

Comment: ^ quick sidenote, there was an extra ")" at the end of @Cooper's answer that I accidentally pasted back into my first response.

Comment: Have you tried escaping them?

Comment: Yeah I don’t edit as well on a mobile device as I do on my laptop.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @Cooper Good thinking, but for whatever reason `ioObject[ioRange[io][0]]=ioRange[io][1]` is working great now for me...✅ js object detection working...✅ correct double quotes and ✅key:value lookups working great.

Thanks again for the assistance, this was my first ever stack overflow question posted after lurking for like the better part of a decade.  Please feel free to post the answer @Cooper, I’ll also edit the question with an expanded solution for reference. ~~ cheers!  